# Any idea why knockoutjs would remove all html content from a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I'm experiencing some issues while testing knockout. I'll be using knockout in a page that already has DOM. Essentially just adding multiple viewmodels to manage set of fields as JS Objects with Observable properties.

I'm having some issues just loading a simple knockout test without wiping the rest of html content on the page. This doesn't seem normal. I was wondering if anyone would be able to point out the issue with this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vcbbg81/xsagzvjz/10/)

HTML:

```html
<span>Why does it remove everything after input1?</span>
<input id="input1" data-bind="value: personName" /><span id="span1" data-bind="text: personName" />
<br />
<span>why?</span>
<input id="input2" type="text" value="2" /><span id="span2" />
<br />
<input id="input3" type="text" value="3" /><span id="span3" />
<span>why are you removing my fields?</span>
```

Javascript:

```js
function myViewModel() {
var self = this;

self.personName = ko.observable('Bob');
//self.personAge = ko.observable(123);
}

ko.applyBindings(new myViewModel());
```

Thanks,
Victor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you close the `span` tag like this:

```
<span id="span1" data-bind="text: personName"></span>
```

rather than :

```
<span id="span1" data-bind="text: personName" />
```

that's work.

but I dont know why, maybe a span element cant be closed like this.

Comment: Right: "both the starting and ending tag are mandatory" for `span` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span)).